# Finding the maximum value of the function $( x^2-x+1)^{ 1/3}$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus

While finding the maximum value of the function $( x^2-x+1)^{ 1/3}$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$ the point where the derivative is $0$ is $1/2$ 
and $f(1/2)=(3/4)^{1/3}$.

Then,  for $f(0)=1$ and for $f(1)=1$... Now here I have a problem, for in my book from both options $0$ and $1$, the answer is only one. Can $0$ also be the answer? Why?

Comment: Did you mean $ (x^2 -x + 1)^{1/3}? $ Your function values are correctly using that formula, but not using the one you've written.

Answer (score 1):

I find $f(0)=f(1)=-1$, but I also get $f(1/2)=-\left(\frac 54\right)^{1/3}$  Are you sure you have the function right?  As written, the maximum is both at $0$ and $1$  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28-%281%2Bx-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%20from%200%20to%201) is the Alpha plot

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = (x^2 - x - 1)^{1/3}$, the derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{3}(x^2 - x - 1)^{-2/3}(2x-1).
$$
So, indeed, the derivative is zero exactly at $x = 1/2$. Now to find the absolute minimum and maximum values, you evaluate the function at the endpoints of the interval and at the critical points, so
$$
\begin{align}
f(0) &= -1  \\
f(1) &= -1 \\
f(1/2) &= \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} - 1\right)^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{-5/4}
\end{align}
$$
The largest value is the maximum value and the smalles value is the minimum value.

---

If, instead, you have $f(x) = (x^2 -x \color{red}{+} 1)^{1/3}$, then the derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{3}(x^2 - x + 1)^{-2/3}(2x-1).
$$
Again the derivative is zero at $1/2$ and now the list of numbers is
$$
\begin{align}
f(0) &= 1 \\
f(1) &= 1 \\
f(1/2) &= \sqrt[3]{3/4}.
\end{align}
$$
Again, the absolute maximum value is the largest value in this list. The absolute minimum value if the smallest value.

One common mistake is that people forget to evaluate the original function to find the max. and min. values.

Comment: So is 0 And 1both correct.I didnt understand what you said?

Comment: @Raul: No, the absolute maximum value of the function is the largest number in the list above. The absolute minimum value is the smallest value in the list.

Comment: Thanks i understood it.But can we say points of maximum value is at x=0,1

Comment: @Raul: Yes, $f$ attains the maximum value at $0$ and at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2-x+1=1-x(1-x)$ and $x(1-x)\geq 0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. The max of your function happens when $x(1-x)$ is minimum. This minimum is clearly zero and happens at $x=0,1$. Hence $\max_{0\leq x \leq 1}(x^2-x+1)^{\frac13}=1$.